# Equivalent way of Excel formulas in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, excel-formula

I have an excel formula which is : `((A3-A2)/A2)*100`. I got the way to subtract two subsequent rows using the below code -

```
macro_data['first_step_fd'] = macro_data['index'].diff()
```

Now I want to subtract the result of the above code with the value stored in A column. Can anyone help me with that? Below is the screenshot of the data -

[Data set image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTVcB.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.pct_change.html#pandas.Series.pct_change

Comment: @BigBen - Thanks for the answer. I got the expected results :)